# Как добавить несколько элементов в массив PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день, Stackoverflow!

Помогите пожалуйста найти решение

Я пытаюсь добавить несколько значений в массив, но при отработке скрипта получаю ошибку

```
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
```

Мой код

```
include("Equipment.php");
include("Subcategories.php");

$ProsperitySubcategories = array();
$ProsperitySpecialists = array();
$ProsperityTechnics = array();
$ProsperityMaterial = array();
foreach ($Prosperity as $key => $key) {
    switch ($key) {
        case '1':
            array_push($ProsperitySubcategories, $Subcategories["1"]);
            array_push($ProsperitySpecialists, $Specialists["1"]);
            array_push($ProsperityMateria, $Material["15"], $Material["16"], $Material["7"], $Material["6"], $Material["5"], $Material["4"], $Material["3"], $Material["2"]);
            break;
        }
}
```

Переменные $Specialists["1"], $Subcategories["1"], $Material["15"] берутся из подключенных файлов, их выкладывать не буду (много строк), но в каждом из них только массивы.

Брал пример с [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php)

```
<?php
    $stack = array("orange", "banana");
    array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
    print_r($stack);
?>
```

Comment: Это как понимать то? foreach ($Prosperity as $key => $key) {

Comment: @Ilya Yaremchuk Я использую цикл для обработки формы, $Prosperity содержит ключи не пустых форм

Comment: $key => $value нужно

Comment: @IIyaY Мне нужен ключ массива, а не его значение, foreach работает правильно, вопрос с функцией array_push();

Comment: @Дмитрий, у Вас там чёрным по белому в ошибке написано, что в качестве первого элемента ожидается массив, а по факту приходит `null`(другими словами ничего). Где определение переменной `$ProsperityMateria` (у Вас её нет по факту)?...может вы хотели написать `$ProsperityMaterial` и просто забыли `"L"` в конце?

Comment: @Дмитрий, и старайтесь избегать прямого обращения к элементам по ключу (как здесь `$Material["15"]`), а если и обращаетесь так, то обязательно проверяйте наличие значения по ключу. (к текущей ошибке это не имеет пока отношения, но с такой записью легко получить другую - никто Вам никогда не гарантирует что по всем нужным вам ключам всегда будут какие-либо значения). Это плохая практика.

Comment: @МихаилРебров точно, ошибка была в отсутствии L. Просто ужас, как я налажал. Перестало выкидывать ошибку. Спасибо! При обработке полей, если поле пустое, я делаю untes() и получаю только ключи тех полей, которые были заполнены. Для моей задачи я не смог найти другого решения. Приму к сведению Ваше замечание. Спасибо ещё раз!